# How can I deserialize nested JSON arrays?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize GeoJson so I can break it up and store it in a Db. When I try to deserialize it, the deserialization of `coordinates` is failing.

I'm using the following class for a geometry:

```
public class GeoJsonGeometry {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string[, ,] coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

`"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.388717, 33.913044 ], [ -85.380885, 33.873508 ], [ -85.379455, 33.866291 ], [ -85.377426, 33.856047 ], [ -85.376403, 33.850656 ], [ -85.364595, 33.788446 ], [ -85.361844, 33.773951 ], [ -85.360491, 33.767958 ], [ -85.357402, 33.750104 ], [ -85.355252, 33.739245 ], [ -85.344054, 33.682684 ], [ -85.342722, 33.675953 ], [ -85.323792, 33.580339 ], [ -85.315340, 33.537646 ], [ -85.314994, 33.535898 ], [ -85.314843, 33.534951 ], [ -85.314091, 33.530218 ], [ -85.313999, 33.529807 ], [ -85.304439, 33.482884 ], [ -85.308211, 33.481579 ], [ -85.309250, 33.483137 ], [ -85.314852, 33.487603 ],...]]]`

I've tried `double [,,]` but it didn't work either.

I'm confused as this looks like it should serialize nicely as it's nested arrays, but it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

I've also tried `List<List<List<double>>>` and `double[][][]` and it always fails.

Comment: can't understand why this question had been down voted, I had the same issue and this post helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Geometry` object should be

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);


public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
}
```

---

**json:**

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -85.388717,
                    33.913044
                ],
                [
                    -85.380885,
                    33.873508
                ],
                [
                    -85.379455,
                    33.866291
                ],
                [
                    -85.377426,
                    33.856047
                ],
                [
                    -85.376403,
                    33.850656
                ],
                [
                    -85.364595,
                    33.788446
                ],
                [
                    -85.361844,
                    33.773951
                ],
                [
                    -85.360491,
                    33.767958
                ],
                [
                    -85.357402,
                    33.750104
                ],
                [
                    -85.355252,
                    33.739245
                ],
                [
                    -85.344054,
                    33.682684
                ],
                [
                    -85.342722,
                    33.675953
                ],
                [
                    -85.323792,
                    33.580339
                ],
                [
                    -85.31534,
                    33.537646
                ],
                [
                    -85.314994,
                    33.535898
                ],
                [
                    -85.314843,
                    33.534951
                ],
                [
                    -85.314091,
                    33.530218
                ],
                [
                    -85.313999,
                    33.529807
                ],
                [
                    -85.304439,
                    33.482884
                ],
                [
                    -85.308211,
                    33.481579
                ],
                [
                    -85.30925,
                    33.483137
                ],
                [
                    -85.314852,
                    33.487603
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this initially and got: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Double' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: @Yatrix I tested it with your *partially* correct json and it works. If you post a **correct and complete** json, we can answer better.

Comment: It wasn't the type at all. It was that the GeoJson data has some arrays nested 3 deep and some that are nested 4 deep. I didn't catch that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yatrix have you got the code and full class model to deserialize geoJson? I'm storing spatial data in the db. Thanks

Comment: @Luther this was over a year ago, I have no idea where this stuff is at or even if it exists any longer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

JSON does not support multi-dimensional arrrays.

That's an array of arrays of arrays: `double[][][]`.